# How to use two-column layout with reveal.js?

Tags: css, markdown, reveal.js

I use reveal.js and write my slides in Markdown code. Now I want to display my content (text, unordered list of bullet points or even an image) in a classical two-column text layout. I would prefer a solution which may be more complex in initial configuration as long as the actual writing of content in Markdown remains easy.

Since I prefer not to run a local server, I write my markdown within the main HTML file.

Update: As the first answer indicates this should be achieved with CSS. (I updated my question accordingly.) Still, I couldn't find any description how to do it with CSS.

Comment: As for the practicalities of "how to do it with CSS" (where to store the file, how to call it), see https://stanford.edu/~vbauer/teaching/revealjs.html

Comment: @Geraldine link is dead

Comment: @wlnirvana I see - I haven't been able to find an alternative :(

Answer (score 79):

I am using CSS flex, it is working fine.

```
<style>
.container{
    display: flex;
}
.col{
    flex: 1;
}
</style>

<div class="container">

<div class="col">
Column 1 Content
</div>

<div class="col">
Column 2 Content
</div>

</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

Since pandoc supports fenced div,

```
::: {.container}
:::: {.col}
Column 1 Content
::::
:::: {.col}
Column 2 Content
::::
:::
```

For the style, we can either use `flex` or `grid`, both work fine.

**Using `flex`**

```
<style>
.container{
  display: flex;
}
.col {
  flex: 1;
}
</style>
```

**Using `grid`**

```
<style>
.container{
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I think this is the best and easiest answer, why anyone would use display: table is beyond me

Comment: A note on this method, to use it with markdown you need to use code like this <section class="hbox">       
 <div class="container">
  <div class="flex-col" data-markdown>
   * Column 1 Content
  </div>
  <div class="flex-col" data-markdown>
   * Column 2 Content
  </div>
 </div>
</section>

Comment: How does this work for Markdown? When I put a div around MD it stops parsing MD inside the div. So I get the raw output.

Comment: You need to have data-markdown in the div after the class name, e.g. <div class="col" data-markdown>

Comment: @Dieshe You may have to have blank lines between the `<div>` tags so the MD parser works properly (it depends a lot on implementation).

Comment: I like this answer because you can do markdown inside the columns. Using markdown, I put the slide title and bullets in one column and an image in the other and it looks great.

Comment: Small addition: In Rmarkdown, the data-markdown statement or blank lines seem not necessary, however, the indentation is relevant: markdown inside the diff worked for me, if the content was not more than two tabs indented, but not otherwise.

Comment: I can't get this approach to work with markdown. I have set `data-markdown` on the divs and removed any indentation with no luck.

Comment: Could you explain why using the grid solution, the `.col` class is not needed ? In my case, it works whatever the name of the class of the inner `div`. But I have to give it a name.

Comment: @Ger a name is needed for the inner fenced div, this is per spec: ["Fenced divs can be nested. Opening fences are distinguished because they _must_ have attributes."](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-fenced_divs).

Answer (score 22):

I created two ID's in an external css file, custom.css, which I attached to my reveal.js file with the field css: custom.css in the YAML header.

```
#left {
  left:-8.33%;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  width:50%;
  z-index:-10;
}

#right {
  left:31.25%;
  top: 75px;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  z-index:-10;
  width:50%;
}
```

I placed div elements with the right and left ID's in my markdown document to produce a two column layout.

```
<div id="right">

- You can place two graphs on a slide
- Or two columns of text
- These are all created with div elements

</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me perhaps because I write my markdown into the main HTML file and I don't use a separate markdown file.

Comment: @jans see the answer from @DiegoP below.  Also note that you can have the whole column of markdown in one `<p>` element.

Comment: My only suggestion is to use classes instead of IDs. You are only allowed to use an ID once, and I'd imagine you'd like to use the `#left` and `#right` elements several times.

Comment: for me, this messes up the print/PDF output, probably because of the float. I prefer Frank's solution below.

Answer (score 15):

[image]

```
.multiCol {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed; // don't fudge depending on content
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left; // matter of taste, makes imho sense
    .col {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: top;
        width: 50%;
        padding: 2% 0 2% 3%; // some vertical, and between columns
        &:first-of-type { padding-left: 0; } // there's nothing before col1
    }
}
```

Put this into your custom theme, i.e. right before

```
// Theme template ------------------------------
@import "../template/theme";
// ---------------------------------------------
```

**How to use? – easy! And not limited to 2 columns:**

```
<section>
    <h3>Doing two-column (this headline still full-width)</h3>

    <div class='multiCol'>
        <div class='col'>
            Gallia est omnis divisa in partes tres, quarum unam incolunt Belgae, aliam Aquitani, tertiam qui ipsorum lingua Celtae, nostra Galli appellantur.
        </div>
        <div class='col'>
            Qua de causa Helvetii quoque reliquos Gallos virtute praecedunt, quod fere cotidianis proeliis cum Germanis contendunt, cum aut suis finibus eos prohibent aut ipsi in eorum finibus bellum gerunt.
        </div>
    </div>
    And simply more regular full-width text in the following. But hey, there is also:
    <div class='multiCol'>
        <div class='col'>Also works for 3 columns...</div>
        <div class='col'>...as we can show in...</div>
        <div class='col'>...this example here.</div>
    </div>
</section>
```

- No float needed
- no clearfix needed
- size independent (→ only percentages used)
- 2 columns, 3 columns, 4 columns ...

`<table>` ist often considered “outdated” (since it got so badly abused for layout purposes in early html days, and still today for html in emails...) but to the contrary at least as a property `layout:table` it has many legit uses, is often the most simple solution and [widely compatible](http://caniuse.com/#search=table-cell).

Comment: Does not render properly if the text in a column is too short.

Answer (score 11):

The [CSS Grid Layout](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/) allows very flexible layouts, two-column formats and more complex layouts.

For two columns, the following CSS snippet may be used. It defines two column templates with equal size, each 1 fraction (`1fr`) of the available width, and a gutter space of 10px between the columns.

```
.twocolumn {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
   grid-gap: 10px;
   text-align: left;
}
```

It can be used as follows

```
<section>
  <h2>Slide Title</h2>
  <div class="twocolumn">
    <div>
      Column One
    </div>
    <div>
      Column Two        
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: While I like CSS grids super much, it doesn't work properly in CSS grids

Comment: @MartinThoma For me, the CSS grids approach worked in reveal.js. Perhaps you would share the issues you encountered?

Comment: Works for me 

Answer (score 9):

I solved the problem with two floating `<div>`-Elements:

```
<section>
  <div style="text-align: left; float: left;">
    <p data-markdown>- This is my first left element</p>
    <p data-markdown>- This is my second left element</p>
    <!-- more Elements -->
  </div>

  <div style="text-align: right; float: right;">
    <p data-markdown>- This is my first right element</p>
    <p data-markdown>- This is my second rightelement</p>
    <!-- more Elements -->
  </div>
</section>
```

I found out, if you want to use markdowns inside the `div`-container, you have to wrap the elements in `p`-tags. If you write `data-markdown` into the parent `section`-Tag, it will be ignored inside the `div`

I hope I could help!

Answer (score 5):

I have found the following way to show one element in such a way it seems to be in a column layout

```
Text going to the right <!-- .element: style="float: right; width: 40%" -->

Text going on the left column <!-- .element: style="width: 40%" -->
```

But actually it doesn't work with more than one element on the right

Answer (score 3):

I could not understand you completely but I guess you may found the answer in  [ramnathv](https://github.com/ramnathv/slidify/issues/142) post.

```
---
layout: slide
---
{{{ content }}}
<div class='left' style='float:left;width:{{left.width}}'>
 {{{ left.html }}}
</div>
<div class='right' style='float:right;width:{{right.width}}'>
 {{{ right.html }}}
</div>
```

it worked for me