# Can a reveal.js slide deck compiled by jupyter nbconvert have two columns on one slide?

Tags: css, jupyter-notebook, reveal.js, rise

I'm writing a slide deck using the Jupyter notebook and compiling it to slides using `jupyter nbconvert FILENAME.ipynb --to=slides`, which uses Reveal.js (if I understand correctly).  I'm consequently writing the slide content in Markdown.

I'd like to have a slide with two columns, if possible.  I cannot seem to make this work.  Here is what I have tried:

- The `splitcell` notebook extension suggested [here](https://www.markroepke.me/posts/2019/06/05/tips-for-slideshows-in-jupyter.html).  This does not work because (I think) it's for RISE, and I'm using Reveal.js.  By "does not work" I mean that the split cells are treated as if I had not split them; it seems to have no effect.
- The CSS suggestions suggested in many responses to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30861845/how-to-use-two-column-layout-with-reveal-js).  While several of the answers to that question successfully let me create two columns, none lets me use Markdown inside the columns, even though several of them explicitly say that they do.  I have tried obeying all the suggestions in the comments as well, including blank lines and `data-markdown`.  Perhaps those solutions work correctly when compiling from Markdown to slides through Reveal.js, but something is different about `jupyter nbconvert`?

Answer (score 1):

The contributed notebook extension [Split Cells](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/splitcell/readme.html) ([repo on GitHub](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/tree/master/src/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/nbextensions/splitcell)) does exactly this.

[This blog post](https://www.markroepke.me/posts/2019/06/05/tips-for-slideshows-in-jupyter.html) shows Split Cells in action.