# How can I fix the reveal-md rendering of this two-column slide (code+image)?

Tags: layout, markdown, reveal.js

I am using [`reveal-md`](https://github.com/webpro/reveal-md) to render a two-column slide with code and an image, taking inspiration from [How to use two-column layout with reveal.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30861845/how-to-use-two-column-layout-with-reveal-js).

A reproducible example is:

````
---
title: "Bad two-columns rendering"
author: "Yours truly"
---

![tux](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2b/Tux-simple.svg/768px-Tux-simple.svg.png) <!-- .element: style="float: right; width: 50%" -->

```python

print("Is the rendering bad?")
print("Yeah!")
print("How can you be sure?")
print("Look at the beak of Tux")

```
<!-- .element: style="width: 50%" -->
````

Once rendered, I get

[image]

If you look attentively, you can see that the "code box" overextends to the right and overlaps with the image (see the red highlighting)

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this directly in the source (markdown) code?
It's a not-so-minor annoyance. I tried fiddling with the markdown above but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to do it by using a little more modern CSS attribute called [`flex`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). I think your problems resulting in some wired template settings of the environment you are using. So here is my second go:

````md
--
title: "Bad two-columns rendering"
author: "Yours truly"
---
<style>
.container{
    display: flex;
}
.col{
    flex: 1;
}
</style>

<div class="container">

<div class="col">

```python

print("Is the rendering bad?")
print("Yeah!")
print("How can you be sure?")
print("Look at the beak of Tux")

```
<!-- .element: style="width: 100%;" -->

</div>

<div class="col">

![tux](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2b/Tux-simple.svg/768px-Tux-simple.svg.png)

</div>

</div>
````

*Here I'm using classes to set the CSS attributes.*

[image: example screenshot]

Comment: The best way to debug it is over the [Developer Console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/open) of your browser (eg. Chrome). Make sure the source code did what it supposed to do... I update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As you're working with float elements you should float both elements and change their order

```css
.element {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

The whole example would look like that:

````md
--
title: "Bad two-columns rendering"
author: "Yours truly"
---

```python

print("Is the rendering bad?")
print("Yeah!")
print("How can you be sure?")
print("Look at the beak of Tux")

```
<!-- .element: style="float: left; width: 50%;" -->

![tux](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2b/Tux-simple.svg/768px-Tux-simple.svg.png)
<!-- .element: style="float: left; width: 50%;" -->
````

[image: example screenshot]

---

PS: Sometimes it helps to set an element to `overflow: hidden;`

---

#### Debugging:

Make sure that the Source Code looks like that:

```html
<section data-markdown="" data-markdown-parsed="true" 
    style="top: 16.5px; display: block;" class="present">
    <pre style="float: left; width: 50%;"><code class="python hljs">
print(<span class="hljs-string">"Is the rendering bad?"</span>)
print(<span class="hljs-string">"Yeah!"</span>)
print(<span class="hljs-string">"How can you be sure?"</span>)
print(<span class="hljs-string">"Look at the beak of Tux"</span>)
</code></pre><!-- -->

<p style="float: left; width: 50%;">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2b/Tux-simple.svg/768px-Tux-simple.svg.png" alt="tux">
</p>
<!-- -->
</section>
```

You can use your browser Developer Console to do so (eg. Chrome the [DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/open))

Comment: The way I debugged that issue was by using revels.js in docker. Just generate a `slides.md` file eg. in the folder `~/revels-js/` and start the docker container with it: `docker run --rm -p 1948:1948 -v ~/revels-js:/slides webpronl/reveal-md:latest`. The result can be seen and debug in the browser: http://localhost:1948/slides.md